# Rundeck Email approval process

Tags: email, workflow, rundeck

How to do the Email approval workflow using rundeck?

We are calling Rundeck from Jenkins for deployment.
Do we have an option such as,

- for DEV environment deployment, email will be sent to DEV lead, and after approval, deployment will be executed.
- for QA environment deployment, mail will be sent to QA lead and after their approval deployment will be done

Similarly for other envs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create [webhooks](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/12-webhooks.html) linked by some web app, this web app can be called by some email link to trigger any Rundeck job. You can check a good webhook tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQlX9pADm7Y) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60400477/10426011) an example to call it.