# Rundeck Webhook to pass an argument to a shell script

Tags: shell, automation, devops, rundeck

I have a shell script which I would like to pass two arguments. The script accepts a hostname($1) and a directory name($2) as arguments

```
just_pull.sh HOSTNAME CONFIG_DIR
```

I have created a simple Rundeck job to run this script when the Webhook is called. I have gone through the documentation and it does not provide a way to do this as I am new to rundeck and its web API's. Passing the JSON value to the URL also throws a null value. I believe I am sending or receiving the data in an improper manner.

How can I define the arguments section in job and how to correctly add the {option.hostname} in Webhook arguments section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60400477/10426011) way. Basically you need to define the argument on the "Options" field (Webhook definition).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @MegaDrive68k for the answer.

To elaborate the answer to my question,

I had to modify the job also. The 'Argument' section has to be filled with, `${option.hostname} ${option.conf}`

Additionally the webhook should have `-hostname ${data.field1} -conf ${data.field2}` as 'Options'.

To call the Webhook, run the following command,

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"field1" : "localhost", "field2" : "conf"}'  http://rundeckurl.com/api/38/webhook/aZmoByl0Hmasked8RkxBT8Oda#webhookname
```

The above command will pass the arguments to my script in question as,

```
just_pull.sh localhost conf
```

Comment: All the tickets on the rundeck github page have ruined formatting, this is the only answer that shows how Options are supposed to be formatted.