# WebHook - Set Nodes

Tags: webhooks, rundeck

I'm developing a webhook to trigger a job, but I can't find a way to specified the target Node who is in charge to execute it, it is possible send in the json payload a param to overwrite the Node Filter before start an execution?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do that is to put an option in your job, put that option in your node filter nodes tab (in this format: `${option.myoption}`) and then call the webhook in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60400477/10426011) way.

I left a job definition [example](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#importing-job-definitions):

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 70a8bdb2-3ff6-419b-8311-394eeb470992
  loglevel: INFO
  name: HelloWorld
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: false
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: ${option.opt1}
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  options:
  - name: opt1
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: whoami
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 70a8bdb2-3ff6-419b-8311-394eeb470992
```

And the webhook call example:

```bash
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"field1":"localhost"}' http://localhost:4440/api/41/webhook/98d1Bp0Pcb8QpIc2OzLodQ5AThtmuP1y#TestWebhook
```